# Understanding pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

I write a few small scripts to python ever so often, but sometimes Pyinstaller does not compile my code right, and i dont have a deep enough understanding to know why.

So i am so sorry that i am posting my whole (i promise) short code, but i have NO idea where the problem could be. The code works fine when its run in pyCharm, so the focus is on why Pyinstaller dosent not compile it right.
When i run Pyinstaller i get no errors, but when i then run the exe i get the following: **Current thread 0x000027d0 (most recent call first):**

So if anyone could have a look through and give me direction to where i go wrong that would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
from math import *
from tkinter import *


def calc_outcome(k,N,n,r):
    a = factorial(k - 1) / (factorial(r - 1) * factorial(k - r))
    b = factorial(N - k) / (factorial(n - r) * factorial(N - k - n + r))
    c = factorial(N) / (factorial(N - n) * factorial(n))
    return(a * b)/c


def runner():
    N = int(PopulationSize.get())
    n = int(SampleSize.get())

    startHand = 7
    avgGameLenght = 15

    print("Draw:")
    string = "    "
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        string += '{:>10}'.format(str(x) + "/" + str(n))
    print(string + "\n")
    holder = []
    for x in range(N):
        holder.append(0)
    for k in range(N+1):
        string = ""
        string += str('{:2}'.format(k)) + ": "
        if k == startHand+1 or k == avgGameLenght+1:
            print("-"*((n*10)+4))
        for r in range(1,n+1):
            try:
                holder[r-1] += calc_outcome(k,N,n,r)
                string += str('{:>10}'.format('{:.1%}'.format(holder[r - 1])))
            except:
                string += '{:>10}'.format("-")
        if k > 0:
            print(string)

def changeEntry(PS, PM):
    if PS == "P":
        if PM == "P":
            holder = int(PopulationSize.get()) + 1
            PopulationSize.delete(0,END)
            PopulationSize.insert(0,holder)
        else:
            holder = int(PopulationSize.get()) -1
            if holder < 0: holder = 0
            PopulationSize.delete(0, END)
            PopulationSize.insert(0, holder)
    else:
        if PM == "P":
            holder = int(SampleSize.get()) + 1
            SampleSize.delete(0,END)
            SampleSize.insert(0,holder)
        else:
            holder = int(SampleSize.get()) -1
            if holder < 0: holder = 0
            SampleSize.delete(0, END)
            SampleSize.insert(0, holder)

vindue = Tk()

PopulationSize = Entry(vindue, width=3, font="Arial, 24", justify=CENTER)
SampleSize = Entry(vindue, width=3, font="Arial, 24", justify=CENTER)
PopulationSize.insert(0,60)
SampleSize.insert(0,4)
knap = Button(vindue, text="Run", command=runner, font="Arial, 16")
knapPP = Button(vindue, text="P+", font="Arial, 16", command=lambda: changeEntry("P","P"))
knapPM = Button(vindue, text="P-", font="Arial, 16", command=lambda: changeEntry("P","M"))
knapSP = Button(vindue, text="S+", font="Arial, 16", command=lambda: changeEntry("S","P"))
knapSM = Button(vindue, text="S-", font="Arial, 16", command=lambda: changeEntry("S","M"))
PopulationSize.grid(row=0, column=0)
SampleSize.grid(row=1, column=0)
knap.grid(row=2, column=0)
knapPP.grid(row=0, column=1)
knapPM.grid(row=0, column=2)
knapSP.grid(row=1, column=1)
knapSM.grid(row=1, column=2)


vindue.mainloop()
```

This is the output from Pyinstaller  (just in case its needed):

```
C:\..\Scripts>pyinstaller.exe --onefile C:\..\Test.py
394 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
395 INFO: Python: 3.4.4
396 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134
401 INFO: wrote C:\..\Test.spec
404 INFO: UPX is not available.
405 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\..', 'C:\\..\\Scripts']
405 INFO: checking Analysis
446 INFO: checking PYZ
473 INFO: checking PKG
480 INFO: Building because C:\..\Test.exe.manifest changed
480 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
2302 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
2305 INFO: Bootloader c:\..\run.exe
2306 INFO: checking EXE
2312 INFO: Building because manifest changed
2312 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
2314 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\..\Test.exe
2711 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

C:\..\Scripts>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on the error message? What exectly is the issue that is written after `Current thread 0x000027d0 (most recent call first):`?